# How to change printed JTable font size?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Basically, I use JTable's method `print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, null, null, true, null, true, null);` to print `this` table. However, on some computers this printed table on A4 sheet is quite small, so I thought I need to set its fonts larger, but I don't know how to do that.

In order to make table font larger, I created a custom `CustomPrintable` class: `class CustomPrintable implements Printable {` and then in its method `print`:

```
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
   ...
   Graphics gCopy = graphics.create();
   gCopy.setFont(gCopy.getFont().deriveFont(20f)); //make font larger, but no success       
   int retVal = delegate.print(gCopy, format, pageIndex);
   ...
}
```

This approach did not help and printed table is still to small. Can you help me with this? How can I change font of the printed table?

Comment: `print` will print the current state of the component, so, with that information in had, you will need to change the font used by the `JTable`, if you're using custom cell renderers, you will also need to make sure they are updated or are using the table's font property.  A better, long term solution, would be to make use of something like jasper reports

Comment: I see, I'll look at the jasper reports how can I achieve my goal.